# Can the default constructor of std::list<int> throw?

Tags: c++, list, exception, default-constructor

I had a (quick) look into the C++ standard and into an online C++ reference, but I could not find an answer to this simple question:

**Can the default constructor of `std::list<int>` throw?**

If so, why would it throw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: it *can*, but it may be implemented in a way that is reasonably safe:

The default constructor constructs an empty list, so there is little need to actually allocate memory in the process. Most list implementations won't allocate any memory for an empty list.

However, the default constructor is not *really* a default constructor, since it has a defaulted argument: `explicit list(const Allocator& = Allocator());`
`Allocator` itself is a template argument, so the *call* of the constructor already might throw, if `Allocator` has a sufficiently dumb (or complex) implementation providing a throwing default constructor, i.e. if the construction of the default argument throws.

*If* the default constructor of `Allocator` does not throw, it is realtively easy to provide an implementation of `std::list` whose default constructor won't throw either. But library implementors are not required to do so.

**Updated:** The `list` has to store a copy of the given allocator to be able to call it later. Contrary to my prior claim, the resulting call to the copy constructor of `Allocator` may not throw (§17.6.3.5, see the comments). The `list` implementation is also not allowed to e.g. default-construct the allocator and do a copy assignment in the constructor, because that would break any code that tries to use the `list` with allocators that are not default-constructible.

Comment: The default constructor of Allocator may throw, but not its copy constructor (forbidden somewhere in the standard).

Comment: _"(...) a call to the copy constructor of `Allocator` (...), which might also throw."_: actually, according to N3337 17.6.3.5 [allocator.requirements] Table 28: `X a1(a);` "Shall not exit via an exception." (I guess that's what @MarcGlisse's comment is referring to) (I don't see such a requirement for the default constructor nor assignment, however, only for copy/move ctors). Also, I have rather heard of "sentinel node" allocation as a potential cause of exception for example when move-constructing a list.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the copy ctor of `Allocator`

Answer (score 1):

The C++11 standard declares the `list`'s default constructor as

```
explicit list(const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

, which does not include a `noexcept`. Thus, the standard implicitly allows it to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It may potentially allocate space via `new` to create its internal structure, so yes, it may possibly throw.

Comment: I can imagine an implementation that wouldn't. But yeah, the Standard allows it.

Comment: Id does not *need* to allocate anything for an empty list. The standard does not specify how an "internal structure" has to be built.