# Can the std::vector default constructor throw an exception

Tags: c++, stdvector, noexcept, bad-alloc

If I construct an empty `std::vector` using the default constructor (and the default allocator), can it throw an exception?

In general, allocating space for the elements of a container can throw an exception (which would be a `std::bad_alloc`). But the default constructor of a `std::vector` does not **need** to allocate any such space; it can lazily allocate some space on the first insertion or assignment. But does the C++ standard *require* that it does not throw exceptions (implying lazy allocation, or catching `std::bad_alloc` and then falling back to lazy allocation)?

Comment: There is a [related question about `std::list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930011/can-the-default-constructor-of-stdlistint-throw).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on the default constructor of `Allocator`. The default constructor of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is declared as

> ```
> vector() noexcept(noexcept(Allocator())); (since C++17)
> ```

And if [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) is used then it's `noexcept(true)`; i.e. won't throw exceptions.

> ```
> allocator() noexcept; (since C++11)
> ```

Hence, before C++17, or if using a non-default allocator, throwing exceptions is possible.

Comment: That does not make sense to me, at least, in 'normal' implementations, the default allocator for std::vector could run out of heap memory and throw, right? The only way the vector constructor can be noexcept is if the allocator is noexcept. What am I missing?

Comment: @ErikAlapää You missed nothing. Yes it depends on the `Allocator`; and if `std::allocator` is used then it won't throw for default construction; which is guaranteed.

Comment: Although *explicitly* required to be `noexcept` only from C++17, is it implicitly `noexcept` in earlier C++ versions?

Comment: Before C++17, the default constructor of vector didn't have a throw specification, which means it was permitted to throw.   Same for the standard allocator.    Practically, if the default constructor didn't actually allocate, it wouldn't throw - and that has always been a common implementation choice, even if not specifically required.